# Python regEx won't identify whitespace

Tags: python, django, regex, dictionary, templates

I'm trying to replace some keywords in a document using Django Template, but unfortunately i'm dealing with normal user data, so my function receives a dictionary with keys that i'm pretty sure will contain a space. To deal with this risk i'm trying to do this workaround using regEx:

```
from typing import Dict, List
from django.template import Context, Template
import docx
from docxcompose.composer import Composer
import re
import django
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(TEMPLATES=[
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['.'],
        'APP_DIRS': False
    },
])
django.setup()


def combine_documents(documents: List[dict], template_data: Dict):
    
    document_paths = []
    placeholder = docx.Document()
    composer = Composer(placeholder)
    
    for i in range(len(documents)):
        document_paths.append(docx.Document(documents[i]["path"]))
        composer.append(document_paths[i])
        composer.doc.add_page_break()
    
    context = Context(template_data, autoescape=False)
    document = composer.doc
    
    pattern = re.compile(r"\{{[\s\S]*\}}", re.IGNORECASE)
    
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        for word in paragraph.text.split():
            matches = pattern.finditer(word)
            # print(word)
            for match in matches:
                print(match.group())
                if " " in match.group() and match.group() == word:
                    print(match.group())
                    print("it's here")
                    paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(" ", "_")
        template = Template(paragraph.text)
        print(template.render(context))
            
    
    return "Ok!"


combine_documents(documents = [{
  "title": "Titulo",
  "path": "libs/plugins/signature/signature_providers/documents/Contrato de Prestação de Serviço - Exemplo.docx"
},
{
  "title": "Outro título",
  "path": "libs/plugins/signature/signature_providers/documents/Contrato de Prestação de Serviço - Exemplo.docx"
}], template_data={"Empresa": "FakeCompany",
  "Endereço Completo": "Rua 1",
  "Cidade": "São Paulo",
  "Estado": "São Paulo",
  "CEP": "12345678",
  "CNPJ": "317637667-0001",
  "Valor": "R$550"})
```

I've already tried all types of regEx i could think of, such as `\{{(.*?)\}}` but it simply doesn't work on key names with spaces (in this example i've tried "Endereço Completo"), even though it's working in regEx debuggers. Am i doing something wrong?

Unfortunately i can't ask the user for a appropriate key name and i can't make a Django Template with filters and all that.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I want to identify the variables in the document model (which are between two curly braces like `{{Estado}}`) so i can replace them with the dictionary values. I can identify all of them, except if it has a space in it's name.

Comment: Are you sure the document you are acting on contains what you think it does?  Because `s = '{{this}} is a test of {{Endereço Completo}} and {{Estado}}'; print(re.findall(r'{{(.*?)}}', s))` produces `['this', 'Endereço Completo', 'Estado']` just fine.

Comment: I just checked and the document is indeed the one containing this section: **{{Empresa}}, com sede na {{Endereço Completo}}, na cidade de {{Cidade}}, estado de {{Estado}}, CEP {{CEP}}, inscrita no CNPJ/MF sob nº {{CNPJ}} (“Contratante”).

O valor combinado no projeto é de {{Valor}} reais por mês.**

Comment: And when i try your method it gives me the error that i was trying to solve in the first place: `raise TemplateSyntaxError(
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ' Completo' from 'Endereço Completo'`

Comment: Ok, i find my mistake and it's really silly, sorry for wasting your time. When i was iterating through every word of the paragraph on `for word in paragraph.text.split():`, it was obviously separating `Endereço Completo` as well. I don't know how i didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. When i was iterating through every word of the paragraph on `for word in paragraph.text.split():`, it was obviously separating `Endereço Completo` as well. Lack of attention.